# Como fazer uma mudança de estilo css via JQuery

Tags: jquery

Olá pessoal tenho um menu de navegação na minha página que a princípio é transparente.
Como faço através do JQuery assim que eu descer a rolagem(scroll) aplicar uma cor de fundo ao menu de navegação .

Este é o trecho de código do html

```
        <div id="nav" class="navegacao">
        <div class="banner">
            <h1>Site</h1>
            <small>Desenvolvedor de Sites</small>
         </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="/">Home</a>  
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="">Sobre</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="">Serviços</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="">Contatos</a> 
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </nav> 
       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav" style="height: 150vh; margin-top: 100px;">
  <!-- Altura e margem apenas para vizualizar a mudança de cor -->
  <nav>Abc</nav>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
  var scroll_pos = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function() { 
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop(); //"scrollTop" obtem a posição vertical atual da barra de rolagem
    if(scroll_pos > 10) { // No lugar de "10", é quantos pixels você quer que o usuário desça para fazer a mudança de cor.
        $("nav").css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
  });
});
```

Obs: Preste atenção nos comentários.